# How to query all polygon has 1 point into

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have 2 table postgresql postgis
1 table polygon (A,B,C,D) and 1 table point (1,2,3,4)
I want to query select all polygon has contain point (A,B,C)
How can i do it.

[image]

Comment: Could you share the table structure and a data sample? Preferably in create table and insert statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `where exists` clause to select the polygons if there 1 or more point inside:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM myPolygonLayer p
WHERE EXISTS (
 SELECT 1 
 FROM myPointLayer pt
 WHERE st_intersects(p.geom, pt.geom)
)
```